# SQL Server : stored procedure is slow when running two left join from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that runs a query to get some data coupe of rows not that big of tables that has two left joins from the same table but is acting slow and taking up to 300 ms with 6 to 20 rows in each table.

How can I optimize this stored procedure?

```
SELECT  
    m.MobileNotificationID,
    m.[Message] AS text, 
    m.TypeId AS typeId ,
    m.MobileNotificationID AS recordId ,
    0 badge ,
    m.DeviceID,
    ISNULL(users.DeviceToken, subscribers.DeviceToken) DeviceToken,
    ISNULL(users.DeviceTypeID, subscribers.DeviceTypeID) DeviceTypeID, 
    m.Notes,
    isSent = 0
    --, m.SubscriberID, m.UserID
FROM 
    MobileNotification m 
LEFT JOIN
    Device users ON m.userId = users.UserID 
                 AND users.DeviceID = m.DeviceID 
LEFT JOIN
    Device subscribers ON m.SubscriberID = subscribers.SubscriberId  
                       AND subscribers.DeviceID = m.DeviceID
WHERE 
    IsSent = 0 
    AND m.DateCreated <= (SELECT GETDATE()) 
    AND (0 = 0 OR ISNULL(users.DeviceTypeID, subscribers.DeviceTypeID) = 0)
    AND (ISNULL(users.DeviceToken, '') <> '' OR 
         ISNULL(subscribers.DeviceToken, '') <> '')
ORDER BY 
    m.DateCreated DESC
```

Comment: In summary, is every record going to exist on EITHER users OR subscribers?  Update your original question with clarification of what you WANT and why you have all those ISNULL() checks going on.  I also see the ( 0=0 OR ... which indicates to me it is some sort of dynamically created SQL statement as 0=0 is always true and will always return regardless of the rest on that line within its (parens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few advices:

- ISNULL check makes queries much slower, try to avoid
- To significantly improve speed, create an index on columns that you filter like "IsSent" & "DateCreated", as well as columns that you group by.
  Also index every table with clusterd index on its id column.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15
- try to avoid twice left join on the same table if its possible. in you case i think you can merge the terms into one line
- and finally- from my experience: sometimes its a lot faster to perform 2 queries:
  supose you select fields only from 1 big table: first just select the IDs in the first query. and then in the second query select all string fields and other calculations filtering previous IDs.

good luck